# How to re-render a child component based on props sent by parent component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an react app, in which I want to change the opacity of the input fields based on the category choose by the user.

This is the code of parent component from where I am sending the property,
as the categoryValue, it should re-render the  component...

```js
class NumberFacts extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            categoryValue : 'trivia'
        }
    }

    onChangeCategory = (event) => {
        this.state.categoryValue = event.target.value;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let value = this.state.categoryValue;
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <div className='tc bg-light-blue dib br3 pa3 ma3 bw2 shadow-5'>
        <h1>Number Facts</h1>
        <NuberFactsCategories  changeCategory = {this.onChangeCategory} />
        **<NumberFactsInputs category={this.state.categoryValue} />**
        </div>
        );
        }

}

export default NumberFacts;
```

**And this is the component where the change listener of the dropdown menu is placed...
It is a dropdown menu, which onChange triggers the function which is present in parent conponent i.e onChangeCategory(), which changes the state od the parent function...**

```
const NumberFactsCategories = ({ changeCategory }) => {

    return (
       <div>
         **<select className='br3 bg-lightest-blue ph3 pv1 measure-wide' 
         defaultValue="trivia" 
         onChange={ changeCategory } >**
            <option value="trivia">trivia</option>
            <option value="math">math</option>
            <option value="date">date</option>
            <option value="year">year</option>
         </select>
       </div>
        );
}

export default NumberFactsCategories;
```

**And this is the component where the input fields opacity must change according to the received property...**

```
const NumberFactsInputs = ({ category }) => {

    if(category === 'trivia') {
    return(
            <div>
            <ul className='tc'>
              <li> <input className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue' type='text' placeholder='Number' style={{opacity: 0.4}} /></li>
              <li> <input className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue' type='text' placeholder='Month' style={{opacity: 0.4}}/></li>
              <li> <input className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue' type='text' placeholder='date' style={{opacity: 0.4}}/></li>
              <li> <input className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue' type='text' placeholder='year' style={{opacity: 0.4}}/></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        );
   }

     else if(category === 'number') {
     return(
            <div>
            <ul className='tc'>
              <li> <input className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue' type='text' placeholder='Number' /></li>
```

**I am unable to re-render this component when the state of the parent component changes.
I've tried the lifecycle methods but I am not getting how to exactly use them.**

Comment: You method `onChangeCategory` in the parent component needs to use `this.setState(e.target.value)`

Comment: try the following `onChangeCategory = (event) => {
        this.setState({...this.state, categoryValue = event.target.value})
    }`

Comment: @sahil are you sure you tagged me?

Comment: @aturan23 yes it is working!...will you please explain how is it working now?

Comment: yes I tagged you

Comment: well, I don't know :) I just refactored :))